# Problem in Changing the Background color of label on Button Click in MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

While declaring the variable and in constructor I can work on the background color of label using MVVM WPF But on other event like Button Event It's not changing the color.

**XAML Code**

```
<Label Content="{Binding MessageArea1Content}" Height="25" Width="830"
       Name="level2LBL" Background="{Binding Path=BrushMessageArea1}" 
       Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
```

**Code**

```
private Brush _brushMessageArea2 = Brushes.Green;

public Brush BrushMessageArea2
{
    get { return _brushMessageArea2; }
    set { _brushMessageArea2 = value; }
}

public HomeViewModel()
{   
    PutCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnPutCommand);

    BrushMessageArea1 = Brushes.Red; //new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red"));
    
    private async void OnPutCommand()
    {
        BrushMessageArea1 = Brushes.Red; //new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red"));
    }
}
```

On `PUTCommand` It's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what `BrushMessageArea2` is doing there, as it's neither in the binding or any of the provided methods.

However, assuming that `BrushMessageArea1` follows the same format as `BrushMessageArea2` (with backing field), then you can update the `Brush` property in your XAML by adding `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BrushMessageArea1)` as follows:

```
private Brush _brushMessageArea1;

public Brush BrushMessageArea1
{
    get => return _brushMessageArea1;
    set 
    { 
        _brushMessageArea1 = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BrushMessageArea1));
    }
}
```

However, do note that this method requires that the class you implement this in inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` or a class which inherits from that.